# Is it possible to efficiently copy an S3 folder to a new name

Tags: amazon-s3, copy-paste

In the S3 control panel I can copy / paste a folder but there is no option to rename the folder whilst copying it so it overwrites it's source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 is not providing rename option.
If you are a developer then you have to delete that folder and re-upload it. 
If you are a non-developer then you can try any tool like [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/). It provides Rename functionality.

**Disclosure**: I am one of the developer of Bucket Explorer